# Printing a values in a tuple in a format

Tags: haskell

This question may seem silly but kindly bear with me

i was intending to print a tuple as

```
String1 - 10

Sritng2 - 20

String3 - 30
```

but if i am

```
putStrLn $ show(tuples)
```

It is giving me the out put as [("String",10),("String",20),("String",30)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Show` instance is meant to convert the data to a string that can then be directly parsed back to the data type using a `Read` instance.  If you want to do something like this, you need to write your own pretty printing function:

```
pprintTuple :: (Show a, Show b) => (a, b) -> String
pprintTuple (a, b) = show a ++ " - " ++ show b
```

With this function, you can convert each tuple to a string, then print those out one line at a time using `putStrLn` and `mapM_`:

```
mapM_ putStrLn $ map pprintTuple tuples
```

`mapM_` is like `map`, but it works with monadic functions and also throws away any value returned.  Since `putStrLn` doesn't return a value other than `()`, it's what you want to use here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the output given by `show` and your expected output, looks like this is what you want:

```
putTuples ts = mapM_ putStrLn $ zipWith showTuple ts [1..]
    where
        showTuple (str, num) seq = str ++ show seq ++ " - " ++ show num
```

Testing:

```
> let ts = [("String",10),("String",20),("String",30)]
> putTuples ts
String1 - 10
String2 - 20
String3 - 30
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also another way to print tuples which offers more control but requires an import of [Text.Printf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v%3aprintf)

Example:

```
> let xs = [("String1",10),("String2",20),("String3",30)]
> mapM_ (\(x, y) -> printf "%s - %d\n" x y) xs
String1 - 10
String2 - 20
String3 - 30
```

You could, of course, make lambda a named function.
I find it useful when there's a lot to print.